# EMF and Distance

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

As a professional underground service locator, EMF and Inductance are at the very core of what we do. Very few of us truly understand the detailed physics behind what makes it possible for us to locate conductive underground services in the way we do.

A colleague and I have been discussing how modern cable location equipment is able to estimate the depth of a target cable.  We know that the EM receiver detects the EMF generated from an induced current in the target service, but how does it estimate the depth of the service?

I assume that the use of two antenna in the receiver is the key to this estimation. Presumably they enable a differential in the strength of the EM field over a know distance (i.e. between the two antenna) to be determine which then allows the distance to the source to be calculated.

Can someone confirm if this is correct or explain how you could determine the distance from a known EM source with one or two antenna with know characteristics and separation.

Thanks, Innes (NZ)

Comment: Could you provide the model of one of the devices you use, or even the datasheet? There could be different working principles for these devices, so it could give us the direction into which the answer has to go. Interesting question!

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest in my question. There are many different devices out there, but I happen to use a Radiodetection RD8000 in my work.  In the research I've done so far around this question, I'm sure Ampere's law comes into play.  Being able to measure the strength of the magnetic field and the current carried in the long straight conductor it would be possible to calculate the radius from the source. The question is then how to measure the magnetic field strength and determine the current carried in the conductor.